# mono + sqlite + linq: memory leaks

Tags: linq, sqlite, memory-leaks, mono

I have a function:

```
    private void FindEmployees(object source, MyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext(conn))
            {
                IQueryable<Employee> employees = from g in db.Employees
                                                 where g.Name == e.Name
                                                 orderby g.Name
                                                 select g;

                if (employees.Count() == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not found");
                }
                else
                {
                    Employee employee = employees.First<Employee>();
                    txtAddress.Text = employee.Address;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My program calls this function every 3 second with random "e.Name" (real names from DB) for test memory leaks.
After 12 hours Linux killed my program, because it have eaten all free memory.

Please, anybody help me!

If I comment the rows below, there is no leaks!

```
  Employee employee = employees.First<Employee>();
  txtAddress.Text = employee.Address;
```